# ASP.NET Core 6 MVC : CSS variable Issues

Tags: css, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-6.0

I copied and pasted this CSS to codepen [The Code](https://codepen.io/albertcardonaii/pen/mdBoOdP).

When I used it for my ASP.NET Core 6 MVC app it doesn't work. If I don't use the variables and just colors it works just fine. Is there something I missed that does not allow CSS variables to work?

[image: Inside the Login.cshtml.css]

[image: BlackBG works]

```css
//the code
:root {
    --fb: rgb(16,148,244);
    --tw: rgb(93,168,221);
    --gg: rgb(234,67,53);
    --lin: rgb(10,102,194);
    --white: #ffffff;
    --fFamily: "Courier New", monospace;
}
button{
    font-family:var(--fFamily);
}
.fb-icon {
    color: var(--white);
    background-color: var(--fb);
}

    .fb-icon:hover {
        color: var(--fb);
        background-color: var(--white);
    }

.google-icon {
    color: var(--white);
    background: var(--gg);
}

    .google-icon:hover {
        color: var(--gg);
        background-color: var(--white);
    }

.twitter-icon {
    color: var(--white);
    background-color: var(--tw);
}

    .twitter-icon:hover {
        color: var(--tw);
        background-color: var(--white);
    }

.linkedin-icon {
    color: var(--white);
    background-color: var(--lin);
}

    .linkedin-icon:hover {
        color: var(--lin);
        background-color: var(--white);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I create a new Asp.net 6 MVC application, and use the following code, it seems that no matter using or not using the CSS variables, the code works well on my side:

```
<div class="text-center">
    <h1 class="display-4">Welcome</h1>
    <p>Learn about <a href="https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core">building Web apps with ASP.NET Core</a>.</p>
    <button class="fb-icon"> Facebook </button>
    <button class="twitter-icon">  Twitter </button>
    <button class="google-icon"> Google </button>
    <button class="linkedin-icon"> LinkedIn </button>
</div>
<style>
    :root {
        --fb: rgb(16,148,244);
        --tw: rgb(93,168,221);
        --gg: rgb(234,67,53);
        --lin: rgb(10,102,194);
        --white: #ffffff;
        --height: 35px;
        --fFamily: "Courier New", monospace;
    }
    button{
        height:var(--height);
        font-weight: 700;
        font-family:var(--fFamily);
        font-size: large;
    }
    .fb-icon {
        color: var(--white);
        background-color: var(--fb);
    }

    .fb-icon:hover
    {
        color: var(--fb);
        background-color: var(--white);
    }

    .google-icon {
        color: var(--white);
        background: var(--gg);
    }

    .google-icon:hover
    {
        color: var(--gg);
        background-color: var(--white);
    }

    .twitter-icon {
        color: var(--white);
        background-color: var(--tw);
    }

    .twitter-icon:hover
    {
        color: var(--tw);
        background-color: var(--white);
    }

    .linkedin-icon {
        color: var(--white);
        background-color: var(--lin);
    }

    .linkedin-icon:hover
    {
        color: var(--lin);
        background-color: var(--white);
    }
</style>

@*without using css variables*@
@*<style>
    button{
       height:35px;
       font-weight: 700;
       font-family:"Courier New", monospace;
       font-size: large;
    }
    .fb-icon {
        color: #ffffff;
        background-color: rgb(16,148,244);
    }

    .fb-icon:hover {
        color: rgb(16,148,244);
        background-color: #ffffff;
    }

    .google-icon {
        color: #ffffff;
        background: rgb(234,67,53);
    }

    .google-icon:hover {
        color: rgb(234,67,53);
        background-color: #ffffff;
    }

    .twitter-icon {
        color: #ffffff;
        background-color: rgb(93,168,221);
    }

    .twitter-icon:hover {
        color: rgb(93,168,221);
        background-color: #ffffff;
    }

    .linkedin-icon {
        color: #ffffff;
        background-color: rgb(10,102,194);
    }

    .linkedin-icon:hover {
        color: rgb(10,102,194);
        background-color: #ffffff;
    } 
</style>
*@
```

The result as below:

[image]

When build your application, is there any warning or error? Whether you are using _layout or not. In my application, there is no warning and error and I'm using the _layout page. You can check it.

Besides, you can also copy the above code to your application and check it. If still not working, try to create a new MVC application and test the above code in the Index page.

**Update:**

As mentioned in the comments, I could reproduce the problem: if using the [CSS isolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/overview?view=aspnetcore-6.0#css-isolation) (add a css file with the same name as the view), the CSS variables not working. You could submit a feedback about this problem to [Asp.net core Github](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/CONTRIBUTING.md).

As a temporary workaround, you can use the CSS isolation without CSS variables, Or if you want to use the CSS variables, you can add the CSS style in the site.css file (in the wwwroot/css folder) or add the CSS style in the `<style>` tag in the view page.

Comment: My CSS File is not inside a style css I use it in something like this
login.cshtml
login.cshtml.css
It works with the rgb() but not with the :root{} variables

Comment: If I add a style tag it works. I was trying to put it in a css file with the same name as the view. As you can see I added the fact it works with regular colors but won't allow me to use the :root{} and variable attributes inside that css file. If I jsut make it regular colors vs using the variables it works just fine'

Comment: Hi @daddycardona, I could reproduce the problem: if using the CSS isolation (add a css file with the same name as the view), the CSS variables not working. You could submit a feedback about this problem to [Asp.net core Github](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/CONTRIBUTING.md). As a temporary workaround, you can use the CSS isolation without CSS variables, Or if you want to use the CSS variables, you can add the CSS style in the site.css file (in the wwwroot/css folder) or add the CSS style in the <style> tag in the view page.

Comment: I was trying to see if it was just me because I knew that about doing it the other ways I was hoping it was just me LOL. Thank you so much I will submit the feedback and put my css in the root folder :)